# CRASH on receiving in-app notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, urbanairship.com

I have a live iOS project which I have integrated Urban Airship for sending Push Notifications. We are experiencing a really odd crash when sending Push Notification + In-App notifications.

For those of you who don't know what is Urban Airship or In-App Notification, have a look at this reference:

- https://docs.urbanairship.com/engage/in-app-messaging/
- https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/#in-app-messaging

The crash info:

```
Incident Identifier: 9A827662-CC1A-4149-A522-A49B6FCB4B44
CrashReporter Key:   99521F07-6C65-4369-999F-E5798EAED769
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:         XXXXXX [1601]
Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXX/XXXX.app/XXXXX
Identifier:      XXXXXX
Version:         2.6.1 (7191)
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2017-12-23T12:51:45Z
Launch Time:     2017-12-23T12:51:32Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 11.2.1 (15C153)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1864282e8
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000186916364 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000185b5c528 objc_exception_throw + 52
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000186916238 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 100
3   Foundation                           0x00000001872b17f4 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 108
4   BaseBoard                            0x0000000188e220cc __40-[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:]_block_invoke + 576
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629b618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 52
7   BaseBoard                            0x0000000188e21e08 -[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:] + 128
8   UIKit                                0x00000001905275d4 -[UIHandleRemoteNotificationAction sendResponse:] + 144
9   UIKit                                0x000000019006e710 __91-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3.2829 + 68
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629f698 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
13  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
14  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bc120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2008
15  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
16  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000188688f84 GSEventRunModal + 96
17  UIKit                                0x000000018fe5b67c UIApplicationMain + 232
18  XXXXXX                       0x00000001003d8e3c main (main.m:15)
19  libdyld.dylib                        0x00000001862f856c start + 0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001864282e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653d2f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 392
2   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x0000000186396fbc abort + 136
3   HockeySDK                            0x00000001010777ec 0x101004000 + 473068
4   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001869166d8 __handleUncaughtException + 624
5   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000185b5c804 _objc_terminate() + 108
6   HockeySDK                            0x000000010106275c 0x101004000 + 386908
7   libc++abi.dylib                      0x0000000185b4c54c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
8   libc++abi.dylib                      0x0000000185b4c5b8 std::terminate() + 56
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a28 _dispatch_client_callout + 32
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629b618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 52
11  BaseBoard                            0x0000000188e21e08 -[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:] + 128
12  UIKit                                0x00000001905275d4 -[UIHandleRemoteNotificationAction sendResponse:] + 144
13  UIKit                                0x000000019006e710 __91-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3.2829 + 68
14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629f698 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
17  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
18  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bc120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2008
19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
20  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000188688f84 GSEventRunModal + 96
21  UIKit                                0x000000018fe5b67c UIApplicationMain + 232
22  XXXXXXX                        0x00000001003d8e3c main (main.m:15)
23  libdyld.dylib                        0x00000001862f856c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186407568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bbed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1420
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
4   Foundation                           0x0000000187211594 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
5   Foundation                           0x00000001872309ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
6   UIKit                                0x00000001909c57b8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 132
7   Foundation                           0x00000001873130f4 __NSThread__start__ + 992
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c2b4 _pthread_body + 304
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c180 _pthread_start + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab74 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001864075bc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186295870 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 68
2   AirshipKit                           0x0000000101324810 0x1012b4000 + 460816
3   Foundation                           0x00000001872edba0 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
4   Foundation                           0x000000018722d894 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
5   Foundation                           0x000000018721d4c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 844
6   Foundation                           0x00000001872ef894 __NSOQSchedule_f + 400
7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000186292a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629af08 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 424
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629980c _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 600
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629fcf4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 596
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018629fa38 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 116
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653b06c _pthread_wqthread + 1264
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018db2f9a4 WTF::HashTableAddResult<WTF::HashTableIterator<int, WTF::KeyValuePair<int, std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> > >, WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<int, std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> > > >, WTF::IntHash<int>, WTF::HashMap<int, std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> >, WTF::IntHash<int>, WTF::UnsignedWithZeroKeyHashTraits<int>, WTF::HashTraits<std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> > > >::KeyValuePairTraits, WTF::UnsignedWithZeroKeyHashTraits<int> > > WTF::HashMap<int, std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> >, WTF::IntHash<int>, WTF::UnsignedWithZeroKeyHashTraits<int>, WTF::HashTraits<std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> > > >::add<std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> > >(int const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> >&&) + 152
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018db2f900 JSC::SourceProviderCache::add(int, std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::SourceProviderCacheItem> >) + 28
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7a560 bool JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseFunctionInfo<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::FunctionNameRequirements, JSC::SourceParseMode, bool, JSC::ConstructorKind, JSC::SuperBinding, int, JSC::ParserFunctionInfo<JSC::SyntaxChecker>&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::FunctionDefinitionType) + 7436
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2efe8c JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 1980
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da8a6d4 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 548
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da88e74 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Property JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseProperty<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, bool) + 1120
6   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2f16fc JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 8236
7   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da8a6d4 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 548
8   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2f089c JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 4556
9   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da8a6d4 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 548
10  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2f1178 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 6824
11  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da8a6d4 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 548
12  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2ef570 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 248
13  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2f21f8 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseReturnStatement<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 264
14  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2ee898 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatement<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 284
15  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7ee10 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatementListItem<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 140
16  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7ec1c JSC::SyntaxChecker::SourceElements JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseSourceElements<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::SourceElementsMode) + 772
17  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7953c bool JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseFunctionInfo<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::FunctionNameRequirements, JSC::SourceParseMode, bool, JSC::ConstructorKind, JSC::SuperBinding, int, JSC::ParserFunctionInfo<JSC::SyntaxChecker>&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::FunctionDefinitionType) + 3304
18  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2efe8c JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&) + 1980
19  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da8a6d4 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 548
20  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da80bc4 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseVariableDeclarationList<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, int&, JSC::SyntaxChecker::DestructuringPattern&, JSC::SyntaxChecker::Expression&, JSC::JSTextPosition&, JSC::JSTextPosition&, JSC::JSTextPosition&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::VarDeclarationListContext, JSC::DeclarationType, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExportType, bool&) + 1188
21  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7f784 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseVariableDeclaration<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::DeclarationType, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExportType) + 76
22  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2ee85c JSC::SyntaxChecker::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatement<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 224
23  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7ee10 JSC::SyntaxChecker::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatementListItem<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 140
24  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da7ec1c JSC::SyntaxChecker::SourceElements JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseSourceElements<JSC::SyntaxChecker>(JSC::SyntaxChecker&, JSC::SourceElementsMode) + 772
25  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da70298 bool JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseFunctionInfo<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::FunctionNameRequirements, JSC::SourceParseMode, bool, JSC::ConstructorKind, JSC::SuperBinding, int, JSC::ParserFunctionInfo<JSC::ASTBuilder>&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::FunctionDefinitionType) + 4280
26  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2f614c JSC::ASTBuilder::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&) + 3656
27  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da93620 JSC::ASTBuilder::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 1844
28  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2f7d30 JSC::ASTBuilder::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseMemberExpression<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&) + 10796
29  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da93620 JSC::ASTBuilder::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseAssignmentExpression<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::ExpressionErrorClassifier&) + 1844
30  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2fb068 JSC::ASTBuilder::Expression JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseExpression<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&) + 104
31  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da9ef70 JSC::ASTBuilder::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseExpressionOrLabelStatement<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, bool) + 736
32  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da9b3d4 JSC::ASTBuilder::Statement JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseStatementListItem<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::Identifier const*&, unsigned int*) + 880
33  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da5c1fc JSC::ASTBuilder::SourceElements JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseSourceElements<JSC::ASTBuilder>(JSC::ASTBuilder&, JSC::SourceElementsMode) + 312
34  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018da57690 JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parseInner(JSC::Identifier const&, JSC::SourceParseMode) + 716
35  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d512f24 std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::ProgramNode, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::ProgramNode> > JSC::Parser<JSC::Lexer<unsigned char> >::parse<JSC::ProgramNode>(JSC::ParserError&, JSC::Identifier const&, JSC::SourceParseMode) + 92
36  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d503c24 std::__1::unique_ptr<JSC::ProgramNode, std::__1::default_delete<JSC::ProgramNode> > JSC::parse<JSC::ProgramNode>(JSC::VM*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::Identifier const&, JSC::JSParserBuiltinMode, JSC::JSParserStrictMode, JSC::JSParserScriptMode, JSC::SourceParseMode, JSC::SuperBinding, JSC::ParserError&, JSC::JSTextPosition*, JSC::ConstructorKind, JSC::DerivedContextType, JSC::EvalContextType, JSC::DebuggerParseData*) + 184
37  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d586104 JSC::UnlinkedProgramCodeBlock* JSC::generateUnlinkedCodeBlock<JSC::UnlinkedProgramCodeBlock, JSC::ProgramExecutable>(JSC::VM&, JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSParserStrictMode, JSC::JSParserScriptMode, JSC::DebuggerMode, JSC::ParserError&, JSC::EvalContextType, JSC::VariableEnvironment const*) + 124
38  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d584324 JSC::UnlinkedProgramCodeBlock* JSC::CodeCache::getUnlinkedGlobalCodeBlock<JSC::UnlinkedProgramCodeBlock, JSC::ProgramExecutable>(JSC::VM&, JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSParserStrictMode, JSC::JSParserScriptMode, JSC::DebuggerMode, JSC::ParserError&, JSC::EvalContextType) + 308
39  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d5841e0 JSC::CodeCache::getUnlinkedProgramCodeBlock(JSC::VM&, JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSParserStrictMode, JSC::DebuggerMode, JSC::ParserError&) + 36
40  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d2fdcac JSC::ProgramExecutable::initializeGlobalProperties(JSC::VM&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSScope*) + 184
41  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d8c8714 JSC::Interpreter::executeProgram(JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 10952
42  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d5bc390 JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 312
43  JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018d92626c JSEvaluateScript + 444
44  XXXXXX                        0x000000010069fed4 executeApplicationScript(NSData*, NSURL*, RCTJSCWrapper*, RCTPerformanceLogger*, OpaqueJSContext*) + 228
45  XXXXX                        0x00000001006a1c3c __64-[RCTJSCExecutor executeApplicationScript:sourceURL:onComplete:]_block_invoke + 256
46  XXXXXXX                        0x00000001006a1dd8 -[RCTJSCExecutor executeBlockOnJavaScriptQueue:] + 168
47  Foundation                           0x00000001873132e4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 336
48  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be97c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
49  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be8fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84
50  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 200
51  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bbd5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1044
52  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
53  XXXXXX                        0x000000010069f13c +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] + 260
54  Foundation                           0x00000001873130f4 __NSThread__start__ + 992
55  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c2b4 _pthread_body + 304
56  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c180 _pthread_start + 308
57  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab74 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001864280f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                       0x0000000185adff34 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 92
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018dc1cd94 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 120
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018dc1cc68 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018dc1caec bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 276
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018dc1cde4 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 40
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c2b4 _pthread_body + 304
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c180 _pthread_start + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab74 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186407568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bbed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1420
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
4   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018682af54 CFRunLoopRun + 112
5   CoreMotion                           0x000000018bc490e8 CLStartStopAdvertisingBeacon + 227260
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c2b4 _pthread_body + 304
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c180 _pthread_start + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab74 thread_start + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001864280f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   WebCore                              0x000000018e6feb88 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 584
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018691ba1c ___forwarding___ + 620
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000186800ecc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
4   WebKitLegacy                         0x000000018fb048b8 __48-[WebFrame(WebPrivate) deviceOrientationChanged]_block_invoke + 112
5   WebCore                              0x000000018f826a08 HandleRunSource(void*) + 684
6   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be97c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
7   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be8fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84
8   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 200
9   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bbd5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1044
10  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
11  WebCore                              0x000000018e6e92c8 RunWebThread(void*) + 556
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c2b4 _pthread_body + 304
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c180 _pthread_start + 308
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab74 thread_start + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186428d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000186407568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868be308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001868bbed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1420
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001867dbe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
4   CFNetwork                            0x00000001870cb128 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 776
5   Foundation                           0x00000001873130f4 __NSThread__start__ + 992
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c2b4 _pthread_body + 304
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653c180 _pthread_start + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018653ab74 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM-64 Thread State:
    pc: 0x00000001864282e8     fp: 0x000000016fa76450     sp: 0x000000016fa76420     x0: 0x0000000000000000 
    x1: 0x0000000000000000     x2: 0x0000000000000000     x3: 0xffffffffffffffff     x4: 0x0000000000000010 
    x5: 0x0000000000000010     x6: 0x0000000000000000     x7: 0x0000000000000000     x8: 0x0000000008000000 
    x9: 0x0000000004000000    x10: 0x00000001865415e0    x11: 0x00000001b9d21ebc    x12: 0x00000001b9d21ebc 
   x13: 0x0000000000000018    x14: 0x0000000000000001    x15: 0x0000000000000881    x16: 0x0000000000000148 
   x17: 0x0000000000000000    x18: 0xfffffff01b69925c    x19: 0x0000000000000006    x20: 0x00000001b79f3b80 
   x21: 0x0000000101a43490    x22: 0x0000000000000303    x23: 0x00000001b79f3c60    x24: 0x00000001b7a00000 
   x25: 0x0000000190b8b5fe    x26: 0x0000000190b953b5    x27: 0x00000001869ae23f    x28: 0x00000001b6182a18 
    lr: 0x000000018653d2f8   cpsr: 0x0000000000000000
```

Do you have any idea of what this could be?

Comment: Seems to be coming from `BaseBoard` by using `[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:]`, 3rd party framework?

Comment: I have got a crashlog that is exactly the same as this.